# How to get CPU revision programmatically in code

Tags: android, system, cpu

Can I get the number of CPU revision programmatically using something like `Build.getSerial();`, instead of:

```
String[] DATA = {"/system/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo"};
```

or no other ways?